# Error:Execution failed for task: Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, merge, dex

I got this error out of nowhere

```
Error:Execution failed for task
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDev'.
    com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

I already tried adding

```
multiDexEnabled: true
```

to my default Config, and other combinations of suggested changes related to this problem

like implementing

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0'
```

also I've cleaned and built a lot

I am also getting this on my logcat:

```
03-12 10:30:06.685 2425-4917/? E/LocSvc_libulp: E/int
ulp_brain_transition_all_providers(), no QUIPC/GNSS transition logic
run due to both engines are OFF  03-12 10:30:06.687 2425-4047/?
E/QMI_FW: QCCI qmi_cci_xport_recv: txn not found. svc_id: 16 03-12
10:30:06.687 2425-3969/? E/LocSvc_LBSApiV02: E/virtual int
lbs_core::LBSApiV02::injectCoarsePosition(const CoarsePositionInfo
&):353]: Error : st = 3, ind.status = 0 03-12 10:30:09.281 808-808/?
E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 32
```

Let me know how I can improve this question, Thanks

Comment: can you show your whole compiles in your dependencies ?

Comment: please attach your app module build.gradle to your question.

Comment: try this. go to your manifest file  and to the merge manifest-layout(currently you would be in text layout ),there would be some possible conflicts and suggestions at right pane of this manifest file.. try to resolve from there ..and let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I had a duplicade Implementation on my gradle file, so removing one of those solved the issue.